# css - div next to each other

Tags: css, html

please see:  http://jsfiddle.net/LSbuC/

I have multiple columns in divs but I would like them next to each other. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

- 1
- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 5

```
    <div class="ui-menu">
        <ul>
        <li>2</li>
        <li><a href="">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="">4</a></li>
        <li><a href="">5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-menu">
        <ul>
        <li>3</li>
        <li><a href="">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="">4</a></li>
        <li><a href="">5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-menu">
        <ul>
        <li>4</li>
        <li><a href="">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="">4</a></li>
        <li><a href="">5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>      
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Float the divs left? ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6EgMM/))

```
div.ui-menu { float: left; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for something as simple as this:

```
div.ui-menu
{
    float:left;
}
```

[Updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LSbuC/2/)